# Multiplicative semi-magic squares

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Magic squares ([Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square)) and Multiplicative magic squares ([Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square#Multiplicative_magic_squares)) are famous.

In this question, let us suppose that we do **not** consider the **diagonals** of multiplicative magic squares. Let us call such mulitplicative magic squares "multiplicative **semi-magic** squares".

The following square, for example, is one of $3\times 3$ multiplicative semi-magic squares.

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $[image]

Note that $9\times 1\times 3\not=9\times 6\times 4$.

Here, suppose that all of the $N^2$ elements of each $N\times N$ multiplicative semi-magic square are **distinct** natural numbers. Also, let $M$ be the **max** of $N^2$ elements of the multiplicative semi-magic squares. Then, here is my question.

> **Question** : What is the min $M_N$ of $M$ for $N\ge 6$? Can we represent them by $N$? Or can we find a good estimate of them?

I would like to know any relevant references.

**Motivation** : I've been interested in this question. I've already got the following :

$$M_3=15, M_4=27, M_5=45.$$

The followings are some of such squares.

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $[image]

I've been able to prove that the above two sets of $3\times 3$ are the only sets such that $M=15$.

**Remark** : Please note that this question is **not** about the smallest possible magic products $P$ which has been studied (it is known that the smallest possible semi-magic product of $3\times 3$ is $120$). You can find a lot of information about this in the following page.

http://www.multimagie.com/English/Multiplicative.htm